# How to freeze all running threads in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, user-interface, freeze, ui-thread

I would like to free all running threads at some point to get callstack from UI Thread. Is there a method call for this?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: I would like to get a call stack from running threads and dump them.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you could just set a breakpoint somewhere in the code and the threads will be paused. In console, you could do: po [NSThread callStackSymbols] to print a stack trace on the current thread.

Comment: How do you get call stack of main thread from background thread? In my situation, when UI thread is frozen, I want to get a call stack from main thread.

Comment: When your app hits a breakpoint, in Xcode's debug navigator (5th button on the top left under "Scheme"), select which thread you would like to work on and print out the callStackSymbols again in console.

Comment: Actually, I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: [NSThread callStackSymbols] will print out the call stack from whatever thread is calling it. So have each thread call that message.

Comment: The problem is that, If UI thread is blocked for some reason, I won't be able to get what's causing the hang since [NSThread callStackSymbols] must be called on the UI thread. Once UI thread is released (finishes its long running task) I won't be able to catch the call stack that caused the hang. Therefore, I need to query this info from another thread however unfortunately, this is not supported i think in iOS

Comment: This sounds like a perfect job for System Trace in Instruments. While I haven't used it much myself, the System Trace monitors all threads during the lifetime of the app and you should be able to see what methods are blocking the thread.